# Excel VBA can't "click" on button at IE HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba

I use a macro to perform a search on a website. However, I can not press the "Consultar" button through the macro.

In Portuguese "Consultar" means Browse.

The source code portion of the page for the button I need to trigger is as follows:

```html
<td style="border: none;">
  <a
    id="Link"
    href="#"
    onmousedown="$('#table-consultar').hide(); mostrarBarra();"
    style="margin-right:5px"
    type="button"
    onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'Link':'Link'},'');return false"
    class="button2"
    >
    <span>Consultar</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

```html
<div
  class="box boxBlue"
  style="padding:10px !important; width: 760px !important; height: 48px"
>
  <table style="margin: 0px; border: none;" id="table-consultar">
    <tr>
      <td style="border: none; text-align: justify;">
        <div style="float:left">*</div>
        <div style="width: 650px; float:left">
          Para mais praticidade, armazenamos as OPÇÕES ADICIONAIS que você
          seleciona e iremos trazê-las pré-selecionadas em suas consultas. Se
          desejar, basta retirar a seleção e esta não será mais exibida. Estas
          opções estão sujeitas à cobrança adicional, consulte seu<strong>
            contrato.</strong
          >
        </div>
      </td>

      <td style="border: none;">
        <a
          id="Link"
          href="#"
          onmousedown="$('#table-consultar').hide(); mostrarBarra();"
          style="margin-right:5px"
          type="button"
          onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'Link':'Link'},'');return false"
          class="button2"
          ><span>Consultar</span></a
        >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div
    id="barraDeProgresso"
    align="left"
    style="width: 100%; text-align: center; display: none"
  >
    <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
      <strong>Aguarde!</strong>Sua consulta está sendo realizada.<br />
      <img
        id="imagem"
        src="https://sitenet.serasa.com.br/elementos_estrutura/transacional/application/concentre/images/ajax-loader.gif"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the macro code I use:

```
Sub Serasa_data(Tipo_doc As String, Num_doc As String)

'IE
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim SubmitButton As Object

'TO COPY DATA
Dim rng As Range
Dim tbl As Object
Dim rw As Object
Dim cl As Object
Dim tabno As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer

'INPUT
Dim login As String
Dim password As String

Worksheets("Parâmetros").Select
login = Range("log_serasa")
password = Range("sen_serasa")

Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://sitenet.serasa.com.br/Logon/autentica"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy
     Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#
Loop

Do While IE.document.ReadyState <> "complete"
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#
Loop

With IE.document
Set htmlDoc = IE.document

.getElementsByName("LOGON")(0).Value = login
.getElementsByName("SENHA")(0).Value = password
.all("acessar").Click

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#
Loop

Do While IE.document.ReadyState <> "complete"
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#
Loop

.getElementById("tipoDocumentoCnpj").Checked = True

.getElementById("cpfCnpjId").Value = Num_doc

.getElementsByClassName("button2").Click

For Each tbl In htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = Planilha6.Range("B" & nextrow)
        rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                rng.Value = cl.outerText
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                i = i + 1
            Next cl
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -i)
            i = 0
        Next rw
    Next tbl
End If

IE.Quit
End With

Worksheets("Main").Select
End Sub
```

But using the command `.getElementsByClassName (" button2 ").Click` is not working.

I've also tried using the codes below and neither worked:

```vb
Set SubmitButton = IE.document.all.Item("Consultar")
SubmitButton.Focus
submit.Children(0).Click
SubmitButton.FireEvent "onclick"
```

```vb
Set SubmitButton = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button2")
SubmitButton.FireEvent ("onchange")
SubmitButton.Click
```

Can someone help me how would I trigger this "Consultar" button?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. So if you want to reference it try setting it to the first element which should be indexed at 0.

I didn't test this, but your code should look something like this:
`Set SubmitButton = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button2")(0)`

Comment: Robert, it did't work as well. It kind of refreshed the web page. `Set SubmitButton = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button2")(0)
            SubmitButton.Click`

Comment: I tried looking at the [website](https://sitenet.serasa.com.br/Logon/autentica) and couldn't find `button2` class or a button with "Consultar". Is it a different site than the one listed above? Also, does the code above get the correct button? You can check in your object browser.

Comment: Two additional things, the example you gave has `id="Link"`, have you tried using `IE.document.getElementById()`? Also looks like there is an `onClick` event in the HTML; you could run `IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript Code:="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'Link':'Link'},'');return false"`

Comment: Robert, you couldn't find a button "Consultar" because it's a step after the log in page, which i can't tell you log in account and password because it is corporate.

Comment: I have tried using the id = "Link" but it also refreshed the page. About this event `onClick` i ran the code as you said and i got the message: "Could not complete operation. Error: 80020101". I'm thankful for your help! Do you have any other suggestion, please?

Comment: Robert, i used `Set div = IE.document.getElementById("Link")
            div.FireEvent "onclick"` and it also refreshed the page. Do you think that could be something wrong with the website? but when i click using the mouse it works! damn...

Comment: There is also an `onmousedown` event in the example above, looks like that triggers a script as well. Try to first trigger that then trigger the next. Other than that, it's hard to tell without looking at the webpage.

Comment: how do i do that? with `onmousedown`